# How to change decimal separator in C# for OdbcConnection

Tags: c#, .net, decimal

How to change decimal separator in decimal in mnoz_obj item the value I recieve is 24.500 and I need to change it to 24,500. The value is recieved from url and I need to store them to database as decimal. One way is to change it when creating URL but I would like to make it in this function.

```
public static string updStavPolozka(decimal mnoz_vyd, int prac, int pvp06pk)
        {
            var dbCon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConn"].ConnectionString;
            string retMessage = "";
            using (var cn = new OdbcConnection(dbCon))
            {
                try
                {
                    OdbcCommand cmd = cn.CreateCommand();
                    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE tableA SET mnoz_vyd = ?, prac = ?, stav = 2 WHERE pvp06pk = ?";
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@mnoz_vyd", OdbcType.Decimal).Value = mnoz_vyd;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@prac", OdbcType.Int).Value = prac;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@pvp06pk", OdbcType.Int).Value = pvp06pk;
                    cn.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cn.Close();
                    retMessage = "OK";
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    retMessage = e.Message;
                }

            }
            return retMessage;          

        }
```

Comment: If you receive a _decimal_ value, build a _decimal_ parameter and pass to store it in a _decimal_ field there is no need of any kind of conversion from point to comma  and you shouldn't convert it. Where do you see a point instead of a comma?

Comment: In Germany thats standart.

Comment: @NicoWalsemann it is not a problem of standards or not. The binary representation of a decimal doesn't contain comma or point. Some bits are used for the integer part and some bits for the decimal part. But when a decimal value needs to be showed on screen it is (usually) formatted as a string according to the locale settings

Comment: I know what u are saying, i have read the Question as "why would u want that". I know why it doesnt work. Sorry Missworded i guess